# code to get value from column when condition is True

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have the following condition:

```
df[‘hour’].value_counts()==df[‘hour’].value_counts().max()
```

i want to create a variable that holds the value of maximum occurrences.
as example:
if max occurrences is `55` at hour `19`, then i need a variable that holds the value `19`

Comment: `df["hour"].idxmax()` - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html

Comment: As a start you will need another column that holds the time of the temperature measurement ... then you can make a histogram of frequency of temp occurrences.

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen there's no temperature measurement and i don't need a histogram i can find the maximum occurrences using .max()

Comment: @DishinHGoyani i tried your code but i din't get the correct answer

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen there is a column for the time which is hour

Comment: @k_a I guess It is confusing what you want from your explanation. Best way to get right answer quickly is to provide some minimum reproducible example with your expected output and dummy inputs. [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @DishinHGoyani i modified the code above. i need to store the value of time (hour) at which the maximum occurs. as example if the max. no. of occurrences is at hour 18    i need to store this value in a variable